# How can I prevent inner-indent after `\begin{frame}` in auctex?

Tags: auctex

In auctex, there is `\begin{frame}` block in beamer. After this coming text starts with a indent. Is it possible to prevent this?

file.tex

```
\section{MySection}
hello world
^
|__[TAB] => nothing happens
```

```tex
\begin{frame}{SomeModel}     | \begin{frame}{SomeModel}
hello world                  |   hello world  
^                                ^
|__[TAB]                         |_2 space added, where I want to prevent it.
```

minimal code that only loads `auctex`:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)

(if (not (package-installed-p 'auctex))
    (progn
      (package-install 'auctex)))
```

Comment: What difference does it make? AucTeX is trying to format things readably to reflect the hierarchical structure, and TeX does not care about the extra space. Why do you care?

Comment: In `org-mode` for the first `hierarchical` I get used to write without space, so when there is additional extra space its hard to get adapted during typing

Comment: Maybe it helps if you customize the variable `LaTeX-document-regexp` or write something like this in your init file: `(setq LaTeX-document-regexp "document\\|frame\\b")`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thanks a lot, `(setq LaTeX-document-regexp "document\\|frame\\b")` solved it. Please fell free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX has a variable `LaTeX-document-regexp`:

> `LaTeX-document-regexp` is a variable defined in `latex.el`.
>
> Its value is `"document"`
>
> Regexp matching environments in which the indentation starts at col 0.

If you use the `frame` environment only top-level in your .tex file, you can add it to this variable.  Use the customize interface or add this to your init file:

```el
(setq LaTeX-document-regexp "document\\|frame\\b")
```

Comment: What does `\\b` stands for?

Comment: @alper - Have a look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html)